# Deploy to an Azure Web App with a private endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have configured an Azure Web App with a private endpoint and want to deploy to it using Azure DevOps. I have found this possibility using Azure Blob storage and Azure CLI: https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/03/01/deploying-to-network-secured-sites-2.html

The following Azure CLI webapp deploy command:

```
az webapp deploy --name $WEBAPP --resource-group $GROUP --type zip --src-url  $ZIP_URL --async false
```

However gives the following Http 403 error: `The web app you have attempted to reach has blocked your access.`

I am using a service principal to login.

Any clues what I am missing here?

Comment: Does the service principal have the right rights to deploy to this web app?

Comment: What rights would be needed?

Comment: (it currently has Contributor rights)

Comment: Contributor should be good. Everything else is setup correctly? You're logged in with the correct service principal? What happens when you try this method of deploying the web app from your machine?

Comment: I would use the build-in Azure web app task that is provided from Azure DevOps. You will connect your subscription and you will select your web app. Then the only thing that you will need to specify is the .zip location. `- task: AzureWebApp@1`

Comment: All set up correctly as contributor. Does not work on my local with the service principal either. When I switch off the private endpoint I can deploy using the same service principal.

Comment: As far as I understand the Azure Devils web app task does not support pull based deployments (which I think is needed), but only push based deployments which use the Web App REST api which is not available on the public network.

Comment: Did you manage to deploy to the app service, with private endpoints enabled? How?

Comment: Yes, using my own devops agent vm which runs inside the private vnet.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and opened a Microsoft Support ticket. That was the answer: There is a problem with "az webapp deploy --src-url": It actually doesn't go via ARM API, but directly to the scm endpoint of the web-app (which is blocked due to private endpoint setup).

[image: az webapp deploy not going via ARM proxy]

There is a bug reported to fix this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/21168

The solution in the meantime is not to use Azure cli command "az webapp deploy", but to call the ARM API directly. In your case its something like this:

```
az rest --method PUT --uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${SUBSCRIPTIONID}/resourceGroups/${RESOURCEGROUP}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/${WEBAPP}/extensions/onedeploy?api-version=2022-03-01 --body '{"properties": {"type": "zip", "packageUri": ${ARTIFACTURL} }}'
```

[image: rest particulary uses ARM proxy]

This call will go via ARM proxy and won't be blocked by your private endpoint setup.

Comment: The command: "az rest --method PUT ..." gives the error: "ERROR: Bad Request({"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\r\n   at Kudu.Services.Deployment.PushDeploymentController.<OneDeploy>d__13.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Services\\Deployment\\PushDeploymentController.cs:line 187"}}"

Comment: Can you paste your full command (custom ids and SAS substituted)? Also make sire the sas, or your link points directly to your file to deploy and not a folder

Comment: Can you add to your answer how we can update the deployment logs? Currently through oneDeploy we can't trace back to the exact pipeline run.

Answer (score 2):

Using the earlier suggested solution, I ran into the following error:

```
"ERROR: Bad Request({"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\r\n at Kudu.Services.Deployment.PushDeploymentController.<OneDeploy>d__13.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Services\\Deployment\\PushDeploymentController.cs:line 187"}}"
```

I solved this by adjusting `"packageUri": ${ARTIFACTURL}` to `"packageUri": "'"${ARTIFACTURL}"'"`.

The full working task for me looks like following:

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: Azure CLI
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'customer a'
          scriptType: bash
          scriptLocation: inlineScript
          inlineScript: |
            EXPIRY=$(date -u -d "$EXPIRY_TIME" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ')
            az storage blob upload -f $(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/*.zip --account-name $ACCOUNT -c $CONTAINER
            ZIP_URL=$(az storage blob generate-sas --full-uri --permissions r --expiry $EXPIRY --account-name $ACCOUNT -c $CONTAINER -n s.zip | xargs)
            az rest --method PUT --uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${SUBSCRIPTIONID}/resourceGroups/${GROUP}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/${WEBAPP}/extensions/onedeploy?api-version=2022-03-01 --body '{"properties": {"type": "zip", "packageUri": "'"${ZIP_URL}"'" }}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If above doesn't work then replace `"` with `'`.
Below works for me

```
az rest --method PUT --uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${SUBSCRIPTIONID}/resourceGroups/${GROUP}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/${WEBAPP}/extensions/onedeploy?api-version=2022-03-01 --body "{'properties': {'type': 'zip','packageUri': '${ZIP_URL}' }}"
```